# windows server 2008 R2 backup issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, iscsi

I have configured and iSCSi drive by using iSCSi Initiator for a windows server 2008 R2 for the purpose of storing backup but when I try to run backup schedule and assign the iSCSi drive as a backup destination it shows the following error 
and I I'm very sure it is not related to space. the iSCSi drive have 1.5 TB storage while the server needs less than 1 TB
I did some search on the internet there are a couple of suggestions to delete shadow copies and delete the backup catalogue I have preformed all but still no luck
any idea or help ?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would see if the file block size is too big on the destination server.  If the 1 TB has many small files, they may consume a large number of blocks.  I would look to see if you have a large amount of virtual memory too.  If a master file table has not allocated the 1.5 TB space, the server may think there is less available space because not all of it is usable.  There may be a configuration problem.  The source may being growing when the process is happening too.

Comment: many thanks for your support ,actually I did create the VHD using dynamic disk but after you mentioned that I have recreated the disk using fixed VHD the issue has been solved !
again many thanks